# windows route not followed

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I add a route on the windows network like so:

```
route -p add 46.137.226.16 mask 255.255.255.255 10.20.1.1
```

The goal is for traffic to 46.137.226.16 to be routed via the VPN/remote gateway on 10.20.1.1.

It works, tracert tells me it goes via the remote gateway, and the server on 46.137.226.16 sees me coming from the remote network (what has a static IP configured for access to Remote desktop on 46.137.226.16)

But when my ADSL local network drops and comes back up, this route is not followed/obeyed anymore.
I can 'fix' it by deleting the route and recreating it. But the whole purpose of the -p flag is to persist the route.

The metric doesn't change, and is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your command:

> route -p add 46.137.226.16 mask 255.255.255.255 10.20.1.1 METRIC 1 IF ##

Where ## is the relevant interface number from the top of "Route Print"

[image: Route Print Example]:

Assigning a metric 1 ensures that this will should always be the default route for this IP.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I don't know the etiquette over here, wanted to give you a up vote, but I don't have enough reputation.